# UIImagePickerController in landscape orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I want the UIImagePickerController to start(and stay) in Landscape orientation code. I tried the solution as described here ([UIImagePickerController in Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083672/uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape))

```
//Initialize picker

UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;


//set Device to Landscape. This will give you a warning. I ignored it.
//warning: 'UIDevice' may not respond to '-setOrientation:'
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

//Set Notifications so that when user rotates phone, the orientation is reset to landscape.
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

//Refer to the method didRotate:   
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
              selector:@selector(didRotate:)
               name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

//Set the picker source as the camera   
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

//Bring in the picker view   
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

The method didRotate:

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
      //Maintain the camera in Landscape orientation
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

}
```

But the solution does not work for iOS 4.0. The app doesnot respond when camera is launched in iOS 4.0. Can anyone suggest a work around to this?

Comment: Anyone please suggest a solution.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468335/ios7-ipad-landscape-only-app-using-uiimagepickercontroller/20468336#20468336

Answer (score 1):

You can use ALAssetsLibrary and asset class to get the pictures in your device and you can use them to display in landscape mode and in portrait mode same like uiimagepicker.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [activity startAnimating];


    appObj=(ImagePickerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if(result != NULL) 
        {
            //assets is a mutualable array...for storing the images that are in the device..
            [assets addObject:result];
        }
    };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
    {
        if(group != nil)
        {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }
        //meth is a user defined method..   
        [self meth];
        [activity stopAnimating];
        [activity setHidden:YES];
    };
    assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator 
                         failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) { NSLog(@"Failure");}];
}


-(void)meth
{
    NSLog(@"%i",[assets count]);

    if(userOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || userOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"haii");
        [scrollView removeFromSuperview];

        scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        NSLog(@"%i",[assets count]);
        for (int i = 0; i < [assets count]; i++) 
        {
            imgBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [imgBtn setFrame:CGRectMake((i%4*80)+2,(i/4*80)+2,75,75)];
            imgBtn.tag=i;
            [imgBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            ALAsset *asset=[assets objectAtIndex:i];
            [imgBtn setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrollView addSubview:imgBtn];
        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,(([assets count]/4)+1)*300 );
    }

    if(userOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || userOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        [scrollView removeFromSuperview];
        scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480,320)];
        for (int i = 0; i < [assets count]; i++) 
        {
            imgBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [imgBtn setFrame:CGRectMake((i%6*80)+2,(i/6*80)+2,75,75)];
            imgBtn.tag=i;
            [imgBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            ALAsset *asset=[assets objectAtIndex:i];
            [imgBtn setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrollView addSubview:imgBtn];
        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480,(([assets count]/4)+1)*300);
    }
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}



-(void)imageClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //for picking the images that the user has selected we are using other array "selectedImages" i.e declared in the app delegate
    ALAsset *asset=[assets objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    [appObj.selectedImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];
    NSLog(@"%i",[appObj.selectedImages count]);
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using [currentDevice endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;  
picker.delegate = self;

// Display the camera.
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

// Given by default your orientation is in landscaperight already
while ([currentDevice isGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications])
   [currentDevice endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Source: [Disable rotation in UIImagePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073483/disable-rotation-in-uiimagepicker)