# How to get Image In Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using image picker in my application.

I want to load the image only in landscape mode.

if it is in portrait mode then  how to covert it into landscape mode...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe,

[UIImagePickerController in Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083672/uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape)

thread can give you answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,I captured image in portrait mode and need to display it into landscape Right mode.

Use the Following code,

```
  let lanscapeImage = UIImage(CGImage: capImage.CGImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: .Right)
```