# How can i open the camera in the portrait mode only in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

Can anyone suggest a way of opening the camera in the portrait mode only in IOS. My case is like this -  i have a parent view which is supporting both orientation. On top of this parent view  i want to present a camera view controller in the portrait mode (independent of which mode the parent view is).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083672/uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the following method in CameraController

```
    - (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations.
return YES;}
```

Comment: This method is deprecated, Now what method should be used ? Behaviour of shouldAutorotate is not same as this method had.