# how to show UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

anybody know how to show UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary in landscape mode just like the photo app in iPhone ?

```
- (void)getPhotoFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType;
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType]) 
    {    photoPicker.sourceType = sourceType;//UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary
        [self presentViewController:photoPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        //[self presentModalViewController:photoPicker animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error accessing media" message:@"Device doesn't support media source" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the answer to [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083672/uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape

Comment: Hi Michael,
it doesn't work for me, No visible @interface for 'UIDevice' declares the selector 'setOrientation:'
when i set [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't show it in landscape form. though the native photo.app can