# iPad camera orientation portrait mode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to set the iPad camera app orientation to only portrait mode.  From the viewController we'll put it in landscape mode most of the time.  Is there a way we can set the camera mode to only portrait?
Like:

```
imagePickerController setOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we can control orientation of camera.Its orientation property is inbuilt,which changes with orientation of device.

Orientation of picker is read only property.

Please correct me,if i am wrong

Comment: actually i just got an idea, maybe we can put the camera in another viewController and fix the orientation. would that work?

Comment: check this  thread ,probably it can help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083672/uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape