# Not able to show the Image in proper format from camera in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on iPad App in Ios6, There when we click the right bar button i am giving an action like below:

```
-(IBAction)camerabuttonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;

   self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
   [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(50, -250, 500, 300) inView:appDelegate.splitview.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

My problem is, When i am in Land scape mode if i click the button. The camera show in portrait mode(Image appears in reverse mode to see) after every second use. But, if i shake the iPad then it shows in LandScape i.e, in correct direction .

see the below images

When i am in Land scape mode if i click the button camera shows the image like below:

[image]

if i shake the iPad then camera shows the image like below:

[image]

I have tried a lot and googled,but I did not find any solution. It's killing my time so if any one have worked on it please guide me and post sample code.

Comment: What exact version of iOS6 are you seeing this on? I cannot reproduce this behaviour on iOS6.1.2/ipadMini or iOS6.1.3/ipadMini.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13763016/1059705

Comment: [picker willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0]; Try adding this code

Comment: or else try adding your UIImagePickerController into UINavigationController. Then add your navigationController into pop over controller and check again.

Comment: we all are waiting for your response buddy .. Does nothing helped you :( ? @Harini Goutham

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try giving transform to your imagePickerController

```
imagePickerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
```

Comment: even i was facing the same problem. This transform code really helped.

Comment: Worked. Use M_PI_2 though, instead of M_PI/2.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue in my project i have tried the below and works for me

**My code:**

```
- (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image {
    int kMaxResolution = 640; // Or whatever

    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);


    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;
        if (ratio > 1) {
            bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.height = roundf(bounds.size.width / ratio);
        }
        else {
            bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.width = roundf(bounds.size.height * ratio);
        }
    }

    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;
    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient) {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    }
    else {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return imageCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I study about your issue in Google search and got some result or possibility like bellow point:-

**result 1**

some Answer say's that its a iOS 6 bug so you can not fixed It like bellow Quetion:-

[iPad camera popover preview wrong rotation and scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766523/ipad-camera-popover-preview-wrong-rotation-and-scale)

**result 2**

I don't think we can control orientation of camera.Camera orientation property is inbuilt,which changes with orientation of device.

[iPad camera orientation portrait mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448231/ipad-camera-orientation-portrait-mode)

**result 3**

you can manage Scaled live iPhone Camera view in center physically move the picker frame.  by Bellow code:-

```
[picker.view setFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset,yOffset,picker.view.frame.size.width,picker.view.frame.size.height)];
```

hope you got actually solution. about this bug or issue

Comment: Actually my orientation issue is...When I turns the Ipad the camera shows in wrong orientation..But after detecting the face..Its coming into the correct orientation.. @nitin

Comment: check this for ios6 oriation :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650137/how-to-change-the-device-orientation-programmatically-in-ios-6

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try a good guess here because I haven't done this myself...

Have you tried to create a subclass of UIImagePickerController and implement the methods of the interfaceOrientation from the ViewController (which is the super class)?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
[popController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(1024, 
  self.view.bounds.origin.y + (self.view.bounds.size.height / 2), 1, 1) 
inView:self.view 
permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight 
animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an ipad app only lanscape mode, I was freaking out because I read all these posts but I used this very simple code to take a picture and it works perfectly for my only lanscape app. Important I don´t choose an image from the library, I just take the picture and use it to put it over an other image, it works for me perfectly.

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {

        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                                animated:YES completion:nil];
       // [imagePicker release];
        newMedia = YES;
    }

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
  //  [popoverController release];

    NSString *mediaType = [info
                           objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = [info
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        imageView.image = image;
        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}
```