# Ios swift camera image picker rotate issue

Tags: swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {}
```

Image retrieved from above code will rotate image 90 degree any solution?

Comment: That's not Swift 3 syntax. Yes, that's not the issue, but please post more code - I've not encountered that issue at any time.

Comment: have try with camera not photo libarary?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Please check this UIImage extension:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    func fixedOrientation() -> UIImage {
        // No-op if the orientation is already correct
        if (imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up) {
            return self
        }

        // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
        // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
        var transform:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        if (imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.down
            || imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.downMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI))
        }

        if (imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.left
            || imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
        }

        if (imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.right
            || imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: size.height);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-M_PI_2));
        }

        if (imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.upMirrored
            || imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.downMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        }

        if (imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored
            || imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.height, y: 0);
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1);
        }


        // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
        // calculated above.
        let ctx:CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height),
                                      bitsPerComponent: cgImage!.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0,
                                      space: cgImage!.colorSpace!,
                                      bitmapInfo: cgImage!.bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

        ctx.concatenate(transform)


        if (imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.left
            || imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.leftMirrored
            || imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.right
            || imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.rightMirrored
            ) {


            ctx.draw(cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:size.height,height:size.width))

        } else {
            ctx.draw(cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:size.width,height:size.height))
        }


        // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
        let cgimg:CGImage = ctx.makeImage()!
        let imgEnd:UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)

        return imgEnd
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you. :)

Comment: Thank you @Kamil but i dont need any processing on image

Comment: In `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {}` method call `let fixedImage = image.fixedOrientation`
Fixed image will be no 90 degree rotated. You can also check this extension: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15850644/4219574

Comment: This worked for me. I just needed to update the code to Xcode 13 and iOS 15. Posted that in another response to this thread. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

The method that you are using for getting image, i.e, `didFinishPickingImage`  is `depreciated`. Using the following delegate function to get the image:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same response as Kamil but code ready for Xcode 13 and iOS 15:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    func fixedOrientation() -> UIImage {
        // No-op if the orientation is already correct
        if (imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.up) {
            return self
        }

        // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
        // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
        var transform:CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        if (imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.down
            || imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.downMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: size.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        }

        if (imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.left
            || imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.leftMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi/2))
        }

        if (imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.right
            || imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.rightMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: size.height);
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(-Double.pi/2));
        }

        if (imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.upMirrored
            || imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.downMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.width, y: 0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1)
        }

        if (imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.leftMirrored
            || imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.rightMirrored) {

            transform = transform.translatedBy(x: size.height, y: 0);
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1, y: 1);
        }


        // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
        // calculated above.
        let ctx:CGContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height),
                                      bitsPerComponent: cgImage!.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: 0,
                                      space: cgImage!.colorSpace!,
                                      bitmapInfo: cgImage!.bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

        ctx.concatenate(transform)


        if (imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.left
            || imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.leftMirrored
            || imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.right
            || imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.rightMirrored
            ) {


            ctx.draw(cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:size.height,height:size.width))

        } else {
            ctx.draw(cgImage!, in: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:size.width,height:size.height))
        }


        // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
        let cgimg:CGImage = ctx.makeImage()!
        let imgEnd:UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)

        return imgEnd
    }
}
```