# UIImagePickerController edited image retrieves wrong image in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have `UIImagePickerController` to select/pick an image from the photo gallery. I have allowed UIImagePickerController to edit (selected) image (crop square frame of image), which works fine with iPhone but iPad can't provide properly edited (cropped) image.

I tried the following suggestion but could not find a solution:
[iPad iOS7 - UIImagePickerController in UIPopoverController has wrong preview image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991654/ipad-ios7-uiimagepickercontroller-in-uipopovercontroller-has-wrong-preview-ima)

Here is code, that I've tried:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

// Update (zoom) visibility of image using pinch gesture & retrieve image using delegate - didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

//------------------------------------------
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


     if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
         // Wrong image - retrieves image different than actual visible in the editing window of picker view.
    }


    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        // Original image, visible perfect in iPad, when imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    }


    picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
        // dismissing image picker
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this method , you will get accurate result.

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}
```