# UIImagePickerController supports portrait mode only. Any alternatives that support landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller

iOS documentation says "The `UIImagePickerController` class supports portrait mode only". Any alternatives to this if I want to display the photo library in landscape mode?

Comment: This is duplicate of: well a thousand other questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController in Landscape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083672/uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape)

Comment: Actually I think this question is much better than the other "duplicates". The other questions have been asked one or two years ago for iOS 3 or 4, and people discussed lots of alternatives that aren't fit for today; now it's iOS 6, so it's better to bring up this question again, and make the situation clearer and more specific to latest OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this will help you out .You can use ALAssetsLibrary and asset class to get the pictures in your device and you can use them to display in landscape mode and in portrait mode same like uiimagepicker.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [activity startAnimating];


    appObj=(ImagePickerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if(result != NULL) 
        {
            //assets is a mutualable array...for storing the images that are in the device..
            [assets addObject:result];
        }
    };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
    {
        if(group != nil)
        {
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        }
        //meth is a user defined method..   
        [self meth];
        [activity stopAnimating];
        [activity setHidden:YES];
    };
    assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator 
                         failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) { NSLog(@"Failure");}];
}


-(void)meth
{
    NSLog(@"%i",[assets count]);

    if(userOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || userOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"haii");
        [scrollView removeFromSuperview];

        scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
        scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

        NSLog(@"%i",[assets count]);
        for (int i = 0; i < [assets count]; i++) 
        {
            imgBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [imgBtn setFrame:CGRectMake((i%4*80)+2,(i/4*80)+2,75,75)];
            imgBtn.tag=i;
            [imgBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            ALAsset *asset=[assets objectAtIndex:i];
            [imgBtn setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrollView addSubview:imgBtn];
        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,(([assets count]/4)+1)*300 );
    }

    if(userOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || userOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        [scrollView removeFromSuperview];
        scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480,320)];
        for (int i = 0; i < [assets count]; i++) 
        {
            imgBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [imgBtn setFrame:CGRectMake((i%6*80)+2,(i/6*80)+2,75,75)];
            imgBtn.tag=i;
            [imgBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            ALAsset *asset=[assets objectAtIndex:i];
            [imgBtn setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [scrollView addSubview:imgBtn];
        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480,(([assets count]/4)+1)*300);
    }
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}



-(void)imageClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //for picking the images that the user has selected we are using other array "selectedImages" i.e declared in the app delegate
    ALAsset *asset=[assets objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    [appObj.selectedImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];
    NSLog(@"%i",[appObj.selectedImages count]);
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't checked whether this is illegal, but it worked for me. If you want the UIImagePickerController to start(and stay) in Landscape orientation code:

```
//Initialize picker

UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;


//set Device to Landscape. This will give you a warning. I ignored it.
//warning: 'UIDevice' may not respond to '-setOrientation:'


[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

//Set Notifications so that when user rotates phone, the orientation is reset to landscape.
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

//Refer to the method didRotate:   
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
              selector:@selector(didRotate:)
               name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

//Set the picker source as the camera   
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

//Bring in the picker view   
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

The method didRotate:

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification

{
      //Maintain the camera in Landscape orientation
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

}
```