# Is mandatory, the device is in portrait position when we access the photo gallery?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a xib file who enter in the gallery to pick some photos, and I define in my project he will support only the orientations **LandscapeLeft** and **LandscapeRight**, so when I click on my button and open the image gallery my application crash and send me a message:

> Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application,
>   and shouldAutorotate is returning YES

Doing a quick search on the internet, I discovered that he could use the commands:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

I put this code inside .m file, but doesn't work! and I keep getting the error message, and the application crashes. So I would like to know if is mandatory, the device is in portrait position when we access the photo gallery, if not, how I can solve this problem?

Comment: yes otherwise use custom image picker for landscape mode.

Comment: yes , you have to use custom picker for landscape mode.

Comment: You do mean `UIImagePickerController` yes? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083672/uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape