# How to put landscape overlay view for UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

In my application, I want to put overlay view for `UIImagePickerController`,and how to display this view to fit landscape mode,the below code displays view in portrait mode.

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
picker.toolbarHidden = YES;


OverLayView *customView = [OverLayView customView];
picker.cameraOverlayView = customView;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Need more guidance on how to set this up correctly in landscape mode.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far in regards to landscape mode? What about what you've tried didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link is useful and solves your issue of `UIImagePickerController`

[UIImagePickerController in Landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083672/uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape][1])